# Creating a Django model with unique values for each user

Tags: django-models

I would like to create a site that helps users to remember meaning of certain words.

```
class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    meaning = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    memory_strength = models.FloatField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I want each user to have individual (unique) value of memory_strength for every item of Word, while values of word and meaning would be the same for each and every user. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You could put `user` and `memory strength` in a separate model with a foreignkey to `Word`, unless you're leaving out something about your problem.

Comment: So, I would have two models: one would contain user and memory_strength, and another would contain word and meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    meaning = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Memory(models.Model):
    memory_strength = models.FloatField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    word = models.ForeignKey(Word)
```